# What’s this sum equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What’s this sum $\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^n c$ equal to? I thought it was $(n-(i+1))c$ but I’m not sure wouldnt it be $(n-(i+1) +1)c = (n-i-1+1)c = (n-i)c$ ?

Comment: Why not consider the case $i=0$ and see what happens?

Comment: Confused can u show me what that looks like?

Comment: With $i=0$ the answer should clearly be $nc$.  Which of your formulas tend to agree with this?

Comment: I see it now, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Factoring out a factor of $c$, you get

$$c\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1,$$

so it's $c$ times the number of integers $j$ so that $i+1\leq j\leq n$. How many such integers are there? Try labeling them $1,\cdots,k$ for some $k$ and see what $k$ is.